# How to get data from WebApi2 using android volley with Content-Type and params?

Tags: android, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, android-volley

How can I connect to the server with Android Volley and getting data as JSON or XML from WebApi2 with defining HTTP Headers **Content-Type** as **application/json** and **Accept** as **application/JSON**?

I have a simple method as HttpPost in WebApi2 like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public String GetData([FromBody]string data)
    {            
        return data;
    }
```

As you can see I use google extension Advanced REST client to test the method and it works properly.
[image]

I set the HTTP Headers and params then server response was what I sent.

Now I wanna use Android Volley to connect to the server and get data by setting the HTTP headers and params but it doesn't work and I just get Error!

```
public void HttpPOSTRequestWithParameters() {

    try {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        params.put("data", "Hello World");

        JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                "http://localhost:15369/api/Test/GetData",
                params,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("Response", response.toString());
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("ERROR", "error => " + error.toString());  
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        queue.add(postRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is the error I get:

> com.android.volley.ServerError

I searched the whole internet and I couldn't find any answers that can help me to fix this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try like this 
Map params = new HashMap
params.put("data", "Hello World");

then on here 
Request.Method.POST,"http://localhost:15369/api/Test/GetData",
new JSONObject(params)

Comment: params.put("Data", "Hello World");